# d3: How to define rect's width same like ticks's distance?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, html5-canvas

I'm working on a project and I need to define a brush that changes the x axis and the rect's width.

I'm trying to define the rect width dynamically which will be set same like the distance between the ticks.
Basically what I need to do is to divide the total width with  `xScale.ticks.length` BUT for some reason I keep getting wrong results.
my code goes like this:

```
var margin = {top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 10, left: 20},
                    width = 1000 - margin.right - margin.left,
                    height = dataset.length*40 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
                    padding = 5,
                    rowHeight = 30;

var rangeSvg =  d3.select("#RANGE").append("svg")
                    .attr("width", width)
                    .attr("height", rowHeight);

       var rangeSvg =  d3.select("#RANGE").append("svg")
                                .attr("width", width)
                                .attr("height", rowHeight);

        var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
                            .domain([new Date(2016, 12, 01),new Date(2016, 2, 30)])
                            .range([0 + padding, width - padding]);              

        var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(d3.timeDay);   
        rangeSvg.append("g").call(xAxis);
        var tickDistanceX = width/(xScale.ticks.length);           
        console.log(tickDistanceX);
```

*

> *example:* for domain of [new Date(2017, 01, 01),new Date(2017, 01, 16)] the result is: 8 ; **instead of 16**
>
> *example:* for domain of [new Date(2017, 01, 01),new Date(2017, 01, 30)] the result is: 15 ; **instead of 30**
>
> *example:* for domain of  [new Date(2017, 01, 01),new Date(2017, 01, 02)] the result is: 9 ; **instead of 2**
>
> *example:* for domain of  [new Date(2017, 01, 01),new Date(2017, 01, 03)] the result is: 9 ; **instead of 3**

*

and then i set the rect width like this:

```
var rect = D3TableSvg.selectAll("rect")
            .data(dataset) 
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .selectAll("rect")
            .data(function(d, i, j){ d.index = i; return d.docs})
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d, i, j){return xScale(d3.timeDay(d3.isoParse(d.published)))})
            .attr("y", function(d, i, j){return yScale(d3.select(this.parentNode).datum().index)})
            .attr("fill",function(d){return color(d.like_count)})
            .attr("width", tickDistanceX)
            .attr("height", tickDistanceY)
            .style("stroke", "black")
            .style("stroke-width", "0.1");
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: I might be wrong, but it would be more logical for me to do:  `var tickDistanceX = width/(xScale.ticks.length-1);` if you want an intervalle.. Then also you might need to apply `xScale` to the width of the rect ?

Comment: nope. it doesn't work. :(

Comment: Then could you add a reproductible example, so we can test, and also be more specific about "I keep getting wrong results".. What is wrong exactly..